# background picture will fill 2 div

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/107/posts/26488/final_image/41-space-scrolling-background850-2.jpg");
}
.container1 {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.container2 {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <h1>Div no 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <h1>Div no 2</h1>
</div>
```

I have this 2 div and a background picture

**Example:**

Div 1: height 250px

Div 2: height 250px

My problem is that the height of the background picture is more than the sum of the two divs. Is there a way that i can fill the two divs without reducing the quality of the image?

**PS**. The two divs is block

Comment: Hi, can you include the HTML and CSS in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you haven't got any code or images. Could you please insert some? I'm pretty sure I know your problem, but I need to be sure.

Comment: you can use overflow: hidden for main div

Comment: @charankumar This will not take effect for background images

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer so you don't have to use px unit as you asked for. Have a look!

Answer (score 2):

Pack both divs to another "wraper" div, set the background to this parent and on background set `background-size: auto 500px;`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try this, in the HTML wrap a class around:

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="container1">
    <h1>Div no 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <h1>Div no 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case 'background', in the CSS style this as follows:

```
.background {
    background-image: url("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/107/posts/26488/final_image/41-space-scrolling-background850-2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

make sure to remove the other background-image from your body.

**Original post**

Try setting `background-size: ..px 500px;` on body:

```
body {
background-size: ..px 500px;
}
```

This will set the height to 500px of your background image.

Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Is there another way without using px?

Answer (score 0):

Check background:

```css
.imageOneDiv,.imageTwoDiv{
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
     opacity: 0.5;
 
}
.imageOneDiv{
   background-color: yellow;
}

.imageTwoDiv{
   background-color: green;
}

.main{
 padding: 0;
background-size: auto 500px; 
  background-image: url("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/107/posts/26488/final_image/41-space-scrolling-background850-2.jpg");
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="imageOneDiv">

  </div>
   <div class="imageTwoDiv">
   
  </div>
</div>
```